# foreach or while only displays last result

Tags: php

This structure will have several pages only foreach or while is only showing the last result, this problem occurred after I made this function, I've seen several questions and is something related to matriz

```
class Layout {
   private $sql, $row;

   private function set_layout($cond, $cond_r) {

     $this->sql = $this->select("*", "table", "".$cond."", array($cond_r));
     foreach ($this->sql as $this->row) :
       return $this->row['name'];
     endforeach;

   }

   public function get_layout($cond, $cond_r) {
      return $this->set_layout($cond, $cond_r);
   }
}
echo $midia->get_layout("WHERE status != ? ORDER BY id DESC", 0);
```

Comment: Well, the return in the first iteration of that loop will actually _return_ , so terminate the method.

Comment: @arkascha as well? did not quite understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you're looking for something like:

```
class Layout {
private $sql, $row;

    private function set_layout($cond, $cond_r) {

        $this->sql = $this->select("*", "table", "".$cond."", array($cond_r));

        $rows = array();
        foreach ($this->sql as $this->row) :
            $rows[] = $this->row['name'];
        endforeach;

        return implode($rows); //Return array of rows AFTER loop

    }

    public function get_layout($cond, $cond_r) {
        return $this->set_layout($cond, $cond_r);
    }
}
echo $midia->get_layout("WHERE status != ? ORDER BY id DESC", 0);
```

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Notice 01 [1] => Notice 02 [2] => Notice 03 )` `Notice
: Array to string conversion in` `echo $midia->get_layout("WHERE status != ? ORDER BY id DESC", 0);`

Comment: Do a var_dump instead maybe? var_dump($midia->get_layout("WHERE status != ? ORDER BY id DESC", 0)). That might give you a clue what's going on.

Comment: @bestorogrammerintheworld return `string(9) "Notice 03"` last result 
Is there any way to convert this array to string with `implode ()`? when `echo` appears the news` Notice: Array to string conversion in echo $midia->get_layout("WHERE status != ? ORDER BY id DESC", 0);`

Comment: @bestorogrammerintheworld worked by converting the array to string `return implode($rows);` edit your answer to tag

Comment: If this solved your problem - please mark it as solved :-)